# JAX-RS multiple classes with the same path

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

With JAX-RS, is it possible to have more than one class assigned to a single path? I'm trying to do something like this:

```
@Path("/foo")
public class GetHandler {
    @GET
    public Response handleGet() { ...
}

@Path("/foo")
public class PostHandler {
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response handlePost() { ...
}
```

This apparently isn't allowed as I get:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: A root resource, class PostHandler, has a non-unique URI template /foo
```

I can always create one class to handle requests and then delegate to helper classes. I was hoping there was a standard way of doing so.

Answer (score 3):

The JAX-RS spec doesn't forbid such a mapping. For example, Resteasy JAX-RS implementation allows for it. The feature should be jersey specific.

Regarding:

> I can always create one class to handle requests and then delegate to helper classes. I was hoping there was a standard way of doing so.

Usually you have the resource classes with the same name as the path:

```
@Path("/foo")
public class FooResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/{someFooId}")
    public Response handleGet() {
      ...
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response handlePost() {
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have multiple resources mapped to the same path. I tried that few days back and landed up at similar error.

I ended up doing subpaths such as /api/contacts for one resource and /api/tags for another.

The only other long way is to create resources in multiple packages and then create different app for each.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue, making the class level @PATH annotation to empty string and moving the resource name to method level @PATH annotation fixed this issue.

```
@Path("")
public class GetHandler {
  @GET
  @Path("/foo")
  public Response handleGet() {
    // impl
  }
}

@Path("")
public class PostHandler {
  @POST
  @Path("/foo")
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response handlePost() {
    // impl
  }
}
```